# Remote branches missing after duplication

Tags: git

I'm having a problem duplicating a GIT repository,
Following the steps described [Here](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).

1. inside */c/dev/temp-repo*: `git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git`
2. inside */c/dev/temp-repo/old-repository.git*: `git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git`

After step 1 I can see that some of the remote branches are missing by typing `git branch -a` inside */c/dev/temp-repo/old-repository.git*.
So after step 2, the new repo is missing these branches too.
Git version 2.7.0.windows.1

How can I duplicate all remote branches? Thanks, Sharon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those GitHub instructions appear to be wrong.  If you want the new GitHub clone to be the same as the original GitHub repository, and for some reason forking is bad,<sup>1</sup> you would need the `--mirror` option on *both* of those two steps.  (Note that `git clone --mirror` implies `--bare` so you can omit the `--bare` part.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Normally, doing a GitHub fork operation would do just the right thing (I think—I don't really use GitHub much).

Comment: Getting the same result using `git clone --mirror`.

Comment: Failed to mention that I'm not using GitHub so forking is not an option.

Comment: Since `git clone --mirror` sets up a bare repository that copies `refs/*` from the source to the clone, it *should* have every (public) reference, including all notes, remote-tracking branches, and so on. What does the original have that the clone lacks? Is the original, which is not on GitHub, using the reference-hiding features?

Comment: `git clone --mirror` was cloning all branches correctly.
I was comparing the mirror to my working copy which had cached remote deleted branches, that were not checked out.
I didn't know that deleted remote branches are not removed from the local working copy and only realized it when I got access to the server and saw they were gone.